# performing onclick validation on particular option in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown menu with about five options and a button that submits it as a form. I was wondering if it is possible to perform validation in onclick, so that you have a different validation for whatever option happens to be selected.

So for example, if the user selects option Milk and clicks the button, onclick will vaildate using method A, where as if the user selects option Cheese and clicks the button, onclick will validate using method B.

At the moment I can only get onclick to use a single validate for all options selected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can write `<form onsubmit="return validate()">` and write a function `validate()` which parse inputs and returns true if valid, false if not valid. If you want further help you should write down your attempts

Answer (score 0):

In your function onClick check your select value

```
function methodA(){
    //
}
function methodB(){
    //
}

function doOnClick(){
    switch($('your-select').val()){
        case 0 :
           methodA();
        break; 

        case 1 :
           methodB();
        break; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="formid">
    <select id="selectid">
        <option value="milk"> Milk </option>
        <option value="sugar"> Sugar</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var validationRules = {
    'milk': function(){
        // validate
        return false;
    },
    'sugar': function(){
        // validate
        return true;
    }
}

var form = document.getElementById('formid');
var select = document.getElementById('selectid');


select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    form.valid = validationRules[value]();
});


form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    return this.valid;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/adYtd/

You get the value of your select option and then use it as a key into an object that holds your validation functions.

```
var Validation_Functions = {
    1: function(x){alert("1"+x);},
    2: function(x){alert("2"+x);},
    3: function(x){alert("3"+x);},
    4: function(x){alert("4"+x);},
}
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    var val = $("#sel").val();
    Validation_Functions[val](" test");
});
```